# Loop that prints twice in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing this bash script that is supposed to print out all the users that have never logged in with an option to sort them. I have managed to get all the input working, however, I am encountering issues when it comes to printing the output. The loop goes as follows:

```
    for user in $(lastlog | grep -i 'never' | awk '{print $1}'); do
            grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1, $3}'
    done
```

of course, this loop doesn't sort the output, however, from my limited understanding of shells and shell scripting it should only be a matter of putting a ' | sort' after the first "awk '{print $1}'". my problem is that the output of this loop prints every user at least twice, and in some instances, four times. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: `grep | awk` is an anti-pattern (remember: awk has pattern matching built in)

Comment: sure, but that wouldn't that mean that it would print out everything not matched by grep? Also, the code works when it comes to printing all users who have logged in

Comment: @Ohunter, `awk '/never/ { ... }'` does the same as `grep never | awk '{ ... }'`, but without the overhead of an extra process and FIFO.

Comment: BTW, see [Why you don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). And specifically for searching `/etc/passwd`, it makes more sense to run `getent passwd "$user"`, which will also work with other directory sources -- LDAP, NIS, etc -- but if you *were* to search `/etc/passwd`, then `awk -v user="$user"  -F: '$1 == user { print $3 }'` will search only for exact matches (not substrings), and only in the one field that you actually *want* to search in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's try to debug it:

```
for user in $(lastlog | grep -i 'never' | awk '{print $1}'); do
        echo "The user '$user' matches these lines:"
        grep $user /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1, $3}'
        echo
done
```

This outputs:

```
The user 'daemon' matches these lines:
daemon 1
colord 112

The user 'bin' matches these lines:
root 0
daemon 1
bin 2
sys 3
sync 4
games 5
man 6
(...)
```

And indeed, the entry for `colord` does contain `daemon`:

```
colord:x:112:120:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
                                          ^-- Here
```

And the `games` entry does match `bin`:

```
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
                                    ^-- Here
```

So instead of matching the username string anywhere, we just want to match it from the start of the line until the first colon:

```
for user in $(lastlog | grep -i 'never' | awk '{print $1}'); do
        echo "The user '$user' matches these lines:"
        grep "^$user:" /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1, $3}'
        echo
done
```

And now each entry only shows the singly entry it was supposed to, so you can remove the echos and keep going.

---

If you're interested in finesse and polish, here's an alternative solution that works efficiently across language settings, weird usernames, network auth, large lists, etc:

```
LC_ALL=C lastlog | 
   awk -F ' ' '/Never logged in/ {printf "%s\0", $1}' |
   xargs -0 getent passwd | 
   awk -F : '{print $1,$3}' |
   sort
```

Comment: So you are implying that it matches the other lines of /etc/passwd and prints that as well? but why would that print out the correct UID for the duplicates?

Comment: You can see from the output that it does, with `daemon 1` appearing twice. Your awk statement always prints the UID and username from the same line, it can't cross-reference

Comment: so would be possible to use some sort of regex with grep to filter it out?

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, and if you read to the bottom, that's what this answer suggests

Comment: @Ohunter, ...possible? Sure. The right tool for the job? Not at all. Think about what happens if you're searching for a username with a period in it -- now you need to make sure grep looks only for a period instead of treating it as a wildcard, which is exactly what it'll do out-of-the-box when not put into fixed / non-regex mode.

Comment: @Ohunter Yes, that's what the `grep "^$user:"` option does. Well, mostly; it'll have trouble if the username contains any regex metacharacters. You can  fix that too, but at this point you're talking about piling workarounds on top of workarounds, all because you're using the wrong tool for the job. Just use `getent` instead; this is what it's meant for.

Comment: This isn't a script that is supposed to be used in any sort of professional environment. Its an extension of a script I was asked to write for one of my classes.

Comment: Then you learned two things already; regular expressions will match on any part of the line; and the proper tool for examining user login information is `getent`. Oh, and that useless use of `grep | awk` thing where just Awk is better.

Answer (score 2):

Just think what happens with a user named `sh`. How many users would `grep sh` match? Probably all of them, since each is using some shell in the `shell` field.

You should think about

```
awk -F ':' '$1 == "'"$user"'" {print $1, $3}' /etc/passwd
```

or with an awk variable for user:

```
awk -F ':' -vuser="$user" '$1 == user {print $1, $3}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Safer to use `awk  -v user="$user" '$1 == user { ... }'` rather than substituting a shell variable into the code.

Comment: Yup -- believe I edited that comment about ~10 seconds after it was posted to that effect. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your grep will match multiple lines, (man will match manuel and norman etc.)  anchor it to the beginning of the line and add a trail :.

```
grep "^${user}:" /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $1, $3}'
```

A better option might be to forget about grepping /etc/passwd completely and use the `id` command to get the user id:

```
id=$(id -u "${user}" 2>/dev/null) && printf "%s %d\n" "${user}" "${id}"
```

If the id command fails nothing is printed, or it could be modified to be:

```
id=$(id -u "${user}" 2>/dev/null)
printf "%s %s\n" "${user}" "${id:-(User not found)}"
```

In gnu linux I'm pretty sure that the found users id not existing isn't possible as lastlog will only report existing users so the second example may be pointless.

Comment: Why use a separate `grep` at all instead of having `awk` do the filtering?

Comment: As an example of why grep in regex mode is an unfortunate choice of tools for this job -- consider if someone is looking for user `Xr.ca`; if `grep` is running in a mode where it recognizes regexes, it'll return `XrXca` as a match, even with the anchoring to `^` at the beginning and `:` at the end.